# cmake: how to reference and build separate cmake project dependency?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cross-compiler cmake project that depends on libraries from a separate project that happens to also use cmake:

```
/myProject/CMakeLists.txt (uses cross-compiler)
/anotherProject/CMakeLists.txt (platform-agnostic)
```

anotherProject can be built completely separately on its own.  It has no knowledge of myProject at all.

Now, anotherProject has numerous modules that I need, like:

```
anotherProject/A/CMakeLists.txt (produces static lib A.a)
anotherProject/B/CMakeLists.txt (produces static lib B.a)
etc
```

When I build myProject, I want to build and link against anotherProject/A and anotherProject/B, to produce shared lib myproject.so.  I'd like to leverage the existing cmake-ness of anotherProject if possible, as opposed to manually globbing its various source sets from myProject.

What's the correct way to achieve this with cmake?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

It would be straightforward if, say, myProject were just a subdirectory under anotherProject, or if there were a top-level CMakeLists.txt that could reference both myProject and anotherProject; but neither is what I'm after.  I know I could build anotherProject and export its libraries to a well-known location, and then reference the export directory from myProject - but I would like to avoid that setup as well.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html ?

Comment: @ErkiAring The issue with `add_subdirectory` is that the separateness of the projects breaks down, if the cross-compiled `myProject` depends on `A` or `B` in the separate project. The cross compiler will start trying to compile the `A` or `B` on its own.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use [CMake packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html).

Basically, in anotherProject, you craft a CMake configuration file where you set variables to be used by myProject (eg. include directory, list of libraries, compilation flags...), or even targets.

Then, in myProject, you use the [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) mechanism so that CMake finds this configuration file and imports the variables/targets in your current project.

There is a [tutorial](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Packaging) on the CMake wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative setup that I can think of based on your requirements is to allow your main (dependent) project to discover the other (dependee) project using `find_package`.

In your main project `CMakeLists.txt` you should add something like this:

```
find_package(anotherProject CONFIG)

if(anotherProject_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Found project dependency: anotherProject")
else
  # change WARNING to FATAL_ERROR if the dependency is NOT optional
  message(WARNING "package anotherProject was not found")
endif()
```

On the differences between `CONFIG` and `MODULE` modes, check the documentation and this [link](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/example.find_package.config).

Then assuming that your main project creates an executable, you could hook up the discovered dependency like this:

```
add_executable(myProject ${SOURCES})
[...]

if(anotherProject_FOUND)
   target_link_libraries(myProject PUBLIC anotherProject)
endif()
```

This should take care of the required include files and definitions as well.

---

Now in the dependee project `CMakeLists.txt` you should do something like this:

```
set(PRJ_NAME "anotherProject")
string(TOLOWER ${PRJ_NAME} PRJ_NAME_LOWER)
set(ANOTHERPROJECT_EXPORT_NAME "${PRJ_NAME}")

install(TARGETS ${PRJ_NAME} EXPORT ${ANOTHERPROJECT_EXPORT_NAME}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION .)
install(EXPORT ${ANOTHERPROJECT_EXPORT_NAME} DESTINATION "share/cmake")
```

This associates an export with a target and then installs the export.

Now, if you check that export file, it expects certain things to be found and `include`d, that could be specific for your project. To make this as supple as possible, you can use the `configure` feature to generate them from a template and then `install` from the build directory.
So, in the project under a subdir named `share/cmake` you could have a file named `config.cmake.in` with contents:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PRJ_NAME@.cmake)
```

In the main project's `CMakeLists.txt` you need to add the following for generating the file from that template:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/share/cmake/config.cmake
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/cmake/${PRJ_NAME_LOWER}-config.cmake)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/
  DESTINATION share)
```

Notice that I used `PRJ_NAME`, because you could potentially reuse that to name the actual executable at the `add_executable` command. It mentally helps if the exported target has the same name with produced one.

This is a more versatile version to accommodate multiple subprojects of [this](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Packaging) tutorial.